# Why does this while terminate before receiving a value? (java)

Tags: java, methods, while-loop

Here's the relevant code snippet.

```
public static Territory[] assignTerri (Territory[] board, String[] colors) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i<board.length; i++) 
    { 
        // so a problem is that Territory.translate is void fix this. 
        System.out.print ("What team controls ") ; Territory.translate (i) ; System.out.println (" ?") ; 

        boolean a = false ;
        while (a = false) 
        {
            String s = getIns () ;
            if ((checkColor (s, colors)))
            {
                board[i].team = (returnIndex (s, colors)) ;
                a =true ; 
            }
            else 
                System.out.println ("error try again") ; 
        }       
        System.out.print ("How many unites are on ") ; Territory.translate (i) ; System.out.println (" ?") ; 
        int n = getInt () ; 
        board[i].population = n ; 
    }
    return board ; 

}
```

As an additional piece of information, `checkColor` just checks to make sure that its first argument, a string, is a string in one of the indexes of its second argument, an array.

It seems to me that when the `while` the method gets a string from the keyboard and then only if that string checks out is a true and the `while` allowed to terminate.

The output I get though is this:

```
What team controls Alaska ?
How many unites are on Alaska ?
```

(there is space at the end to type in an input)

This would seem to suggest that the `while` terminates before an input is ever typed in since the first line of text is within the `while` while the second line of text comes after it outside of it.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you confused `=` with `==` ?

Comment: Yep, while (a = false)  should be changed to while (a == false)

Comment: Normally in Java when you confuse `=` and `==` in a `while` condition, you get a compiler error, you bang your head on your desk, and you fix it. But for the `boolean` type `while (a = false)` is a statement with a valid condition, so the compiler doesn't stop you.

Comment: Hehe, I used to do this too after doing too much Python. =P

Comment: that's why I always use the convention const == var and not var == const. that way the day I forget one = the compiler will refuse to compile regardless of langauge and typ

Comment: No, its why you use the convention var and !var for boolean types in java.

Answer (score 6):

Because you need to use

```
while (a == false)
```

or

```
while (!a)
```

instead.

('=' is the assignment operator. '==' is a comparison operator. You need to use a comparison operator in this instance.)

Comment: while (!a) is the best option

Comment: @Joel Oh, agreed. Just mentioning options.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use == rather than = to make an 'equals' comparison.

Either

```
while (a == false)
```

or

```
while (!a)
```

will work. !a means not a.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the issue is solved by previous answers, I Would recommend rewriting the break condition as an explicit break.

```
while (true) 
{
    String s = getIns () ;
    if (checkColor(s, colors))
    {
        board[i].team = returnIndex(s, colors);
        break; 
    }
    System.out.println("error try again"); 
}
```

Or write the code more like how you would describe it in English. "Ask for a new answer until satisfied".

```
String s = getIns();
while (!checkColor(s, colors))
{
    // Ask for a new answer until satisfied
    System.out.println ("error try again");
    s = getIns();
}
board[i].team = returnIndex(s, colors);
```

The intention of the code is more clear this way imho.

Comment: It exits the loop at that point - regardless of the while conditions. If you want to write good, structured code you should always try to use a boolean condition rather than breaks, though.